# WebLogic Hostname verification problems

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have the following setup using Weblogic 12c on a Centos8 server:
There is one domain, that consists of two machines (machine0 and machine1). 
Nodemanager is configured for both, and the admin console also tells me, that both nodemanagers are reachable. Both of the machines ip adresses are set in the /etc/hosts file to machine0 and machine1.
Hostname verification is disabled in the admin server, as well as in the nodemanager's properties files. So far so good.

Furthermore I'm using custom certificates in two jks stores (ID nd Trust) which have been verified to work in a different scenario (just using localhost in two "machines").

Now I create a new managed server via the admin console (doesn't matter for which machine) with hostname verification turned OFF in the SSL tab (all other necessary SSL settings are valid).
If I try to start it right after creation via the admin console (nodemanager is reachable!) the server log tells me:

```
<BEA-090960> <The server's SSL configuration is not available. There will potentially be SSL handshake failures.> 
<BEA-090924> <JSSE has been selected by default, since the SSLMBean is not available.> 
<Security> <BEA-090908> <Using the default WebLogic SSL Hostname Verifier implementation.>
```

Leading to:

```
<Info> <Management> <BEA-141298> <Could not register with the Administration Server: java.rmi.RemoteException: [Deployer:149150]An IOException occurred while reading the input.; nested exception is: 
    javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier,
```

But it also tells me, that it was able to load trusted certs from my defined Trust store:

```
<Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the jks keystore file /home/iffuw/Documents/keystores/TrustStore.jks.>
```

The only way to start the server right after creation and correct configuration in the described manner is to add this option to the "startWeblogic" script in the domain's /bin folder.

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true"
```

to disable hostname verification via a JVM argument.
Once the server booted up, I can comment out that line again, since ALL SSL settings seem to have taken effect now.

So it looks like all custom SSL settings (my custom ID and trust stores, otherwise no SSL connection to the AdminServer would be possible) are transferred at the first server start via admin console and nodemanager, but NOT the setting to ignore hostname verification.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am not sure about your question, however, hostname verification can be set through admin console too. More details at https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/SECMG/hostname_verifier.htm#SECMG684

Comment: Yes, I know that. It did turn it off in the admin console. However, when starting the server for the firsr time via the asmin console and nodemanager, this setting is ignored. Just as I lined out above...

Comment: startScriptEnabled is True or False in your nodemanager.properties?

Comment: this property is set to true